# How to manually add a document to a collection in Firestore database?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I have a quite simple database in Firestore (geographic name, lat and Lon). The database is very static and I only need to add or remove a record (document) once a while.
How can I add a record manually to the collection, with the same fields as the other documents? When I press "Add document" the console asks me to input each field (see screenshot).
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add them manually, each property, one by one?

Comment: Document storage doesn't really have the concept of "same fields" like SQL has. I doubt Firestore offers that kind of feature out of the box.

Comment: You could develop very rapidly an HTML form to do so, with Firebase this development can be done in 5 to 10 minutes, depending on the number of fields.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec: any helper link?

Comment: @FabioMarzocca See the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following HTML page will allow you to write to your `spots` Firestore collection.

You need to adapt the fields, of course, as well as the Firebase config.

If you want to authenticate, just add two extra fields e.g. Username and Password and use the [`signInWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth?authuser=0#signinwithemailandpassword) method. (I can adapt the page if you want).

You can host this page in Firebase hosting for example, taking advantage of the SSL Certificate. Or you can simply save it on your computer and open it with a browser (not HTTPS in this case, but a good way to test).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Firebase Form</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <p>Name:</p>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" />

      <p>City:</p>

      <input type="text" placeholder="City" id="city" />

      <br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" id="submit" />
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
          apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var database = firebase.firestore();

        $('#submit').on('click', function() {
          var nameValue = $('#name').val();
          var cityValue = $('#city').val();

          var dataObject = {
            name: nameValue,
            city: cityValue
          };

          database.collection('spots').add(dataObject);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if someone coming here is also a newbie in firebase like me, then make sure to select **Cloud Firestore** instead of **Realtime database**, this html file was successfully able to create a collection in cloud firestore and then document there as well

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you'll have to write or use a tool to do this.