# unable to add Firebase document using a web page

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add firebasefirestore documents using web page to avoid doing that manually from firebase console using this form

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Firebase Form</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <p>Name:</p>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" />

      <p>City:</p>

      <input type="text" placeholder="City" id="city" />

      <br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" id="submit" />
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
          apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var database = firebase.firestore();

        $('#submit').on('click', function() {
          var nameValue = $('#name').val();
          var cityValue = $('#city').val();

          var dataObject = {
            name: nameValue,
            city: cityValue
          };

          database.collection('spots').add(dataObject);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but it just works on my computer not any other computer
even when i copied the code to a new text document and saved as html
so please help me and this would be Appreciated

Comment: what error do u get

Comment: the error is it works just on my computer not any other computer

Comment: should i do something to solve the problem of making it available to any computer?

Comment: i used the accepted answer of this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131113/how-to-manually-add-a-document-to-a-collection-in-firestore-database#

Comment: what do u mean on only ur computer.. is this code deployed to a hosting server?.. If you are just testing on localhost.. then you need to move the files to the other computer also

Comment: i moved the page to another computer but it is not working

Comment: what should i also do peter